# There was an error processing your settings.json file: process is not defined

Tags: mysql, node.js, etherpad, vmc

when I push my code of etherpad, it said that

[31m[2012-11-03 15:14:00.102] [ERROR] console - [39mThere was an error process
ing your settings.json file: process is not defined

this key code is below

```
/*
  This file must be valid JSON. But comments are allowed

  Please edit settings.json, not settings.json.template
*/
{
  //Ip and port which etherpad should bind at
  "ip": process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST,
  "port" : process.env.VCAP_APP_POR,

  //The Type of the database. You can choose between dirty, postgres, sqlite and mysql
  //You shouldn't use "dirty" for for anything else than testing or development
  /*"dbType" : "dirty",*/
  //the database specific settings
  /*"dbSettings" : {
                   "filename" : "var/dirty.db"
                 },*/

  /* An Example of MySQL Configuration */
   "dbType" : "mysql",
   "dbSettings" : {
                    "user"    : process.env.VCAP_SERVICES["etherpadDB"][0]["credentials"]["user"], 
                    "host"    : process.env.VCAP_SERVICES["etherpadDB"][0]["host"], 
                    "password": process.env.VCAP_SERVICES["etherpadDB"][0]["password"], 
                    "database": process.env.VCAP_SERVICES["etherpadDB"][0]["name"]
                  },



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is surely because your file is not valid JSON. JSON does not have a value type of "process." If you rewrite the file using the actual values rather than references, it should work.

So instead of:

```
"ip": process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST
```

use the value of the referenced variable, as in:

```
"ip": "10.0.0.1"
```

See http://www.json.org/ for how to write JSON.

**EDIT**

Since you need to update the contents of the JSON config file from variables that Cloud Foundry keeps in the process environment, you'll need to modify your EtherPad Lite installation to rebuild the `settings.json` file each time you start EtherPad Lite.

Please see:

https://github.com/raisch/sandbox/blob/master/EtherPadLite-CloudFoundry/buildConfigFile.js

for instructions on how to update your EtherPad Lite.

Please note that as I do not have an account at Cloud Foundry, I cannot test this in place.  However, assuming that the process environment contains the values you reference in your example, this will create a valid `settings.json` file every time you start your EtherPad Lite instance.

Comment: thanks for your answer,but I will push it to app-fog or cloud foundry,I don't know ip or prot before the service is running.And the document says I should use process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST in Node.js server.but it seems not work.

Comment: Yes, Cloud Foundry's node auto-configuration uses those values but you cannot simply insert them into a JSON file and expect them to work. At the very least, you'd need to be able to evaluate the file you have (as a JavaScript object) and then JSON.stringify it to the local file system for EtherPad to recognize it. It should also be noted that Cloud Foundry __does not list EtherPad__ as a service with auto-configuration support as per: http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/08/14/cloud-foundry-now-supports-auto-reconfiguration-for-node-js-applications/